# Is "Where and how to safely buy X drug in Y city?" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

As most of you already know, in many countries, doing drugs are parts of their culture and rituals and is considered healthy even if it's declared illegal by the authorities. e.g. Psilocybin mushrooms have been recently banned in Bali and few other touristic islands in Indonesia.

So it might be a traveler's question to know how and where to buy a so-called-drug safely. As there are a lot of scams and traps running against tourists.

I went through the help and I couldn't find any reasons not to ask such questions on Travel SE. Is "Where and how to safely buy X drug in Y city?" off-topic? And if yes, why?

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay to ask:

- How do I buy marijuana in Colorado? (legal at state level)
- How do I buy weed in Amsterdam? (officially tolerated by the government)
- How do I buy medical marijuana in Canada? (legal for medical purposes)
- Where do I buy Warfarin in Tajikistan? (legal drug as long as you have a prescription)

Not okay to ask:

- How do I buy mushrooms in Bali? (illegal on every level)
- Where do I get cocaine in New York? (likewise illegal)

StackExchange is not a place for asking questions about violating a law. We're not an underground site and won't encourage illicit activity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if one just wants to know about the safety level of using an illegal drug on a city he has the intention to travel to? Not the how and where of it. For example, one asks "Is LSD blotters safe to purchase in Tehran?", or "Are LSD blotters that are being sold in Bali streets are all fake?". Now, it's not about violating a law.

Comment: @sepehr still not okay. Although you may ask 'What is the punishment for buying LSD in Bali?'

Comment: @JonathanReez wouldn't that be more of a legal question, rather than travel? Otherwise we open to 'what is the punishment for [insert any item here] in [place]?"

Comment: @MarkMayo how about 'Are tourists​ known to be jailed for buying drugs in X?'

Comment: @JonathanReez perhaps. Probably *more* suitable, although answerable with a simple google so it might get downvotes for lack of research ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo the main cases that hit the newspaper headlines in Australia I'm aware of are mainly to do with trafficking commercial quantities (Corby, Bali Nine, that South American case), rather than possession.